# How can I create an Azure Auth Token in a blobTrigger Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to create a new Storage Account resource from an Azure Function.  I am trying to use a StorageManagementClient, and need to pass in a ServiceClientCredential.

My code feels too simple... it compiles, but I feel like I must be missing some params.  I am passing in a subscriptionId and a tenantId of an account in my subscription.

```
    AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", tenantId);
    ServiceClientCredentials credentials = new TokenCredentials(accessToken);
    StorageManagementClient StorageManagement = new StorageManagementClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
```

When it runs, I get the following error:

```
2021-02-12T03:32:26.407 [Error] Executed 'BlobTrigger1' (Failed, Id=9c293b8d-591e-420e-b376-dc9ac45097cc, Duration=343ms)Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://management.azure.com/, Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/cd256644-73f5-4da4-af5d-4a977f7a6a5d. Exception Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://management.azure.com/, Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/cd256644-73f5-4da4-af5d-4a977f7a6a5d. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://management.azure.com/, Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/cd256644-73f5-4da4-af5d-4a977f7a6a5d. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Visual Studio token provider file not found at "D:\local\LocalAppData\.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json"Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://management.azure.com/, Authority: https://login.microsoftonline.com/cd256644-73f5-4da4-af5d-4a977f7a6a5d. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. 'az' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. I have found this [issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/3933) is similar to yours. You can try this:

> Hi friends, I have little ability to write fancy workaround code (my
> head is not there), but by what you said above, I harkened back to
> some old advice of: In the tool bar at the top of your VS 2017 program
> go to: Tools, Options, Azure Service Authentication, Account
> Selection, click the drop arrow on the right of the Microsoft banner
> with your account name on it, click your account pop-up
> again...hard(really insist on it), and that worked. I really feel like
> a "just fix it" here might be just fine for a lot of folks. Don't get
> me wrong, you girls(guys) know it better. Boy did I just want it to
> work (phew!) Thanks :)

If that can't solve your problem, you can try this [code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-dotnet-resource-provider-getting-started/blob/master/Program.cs#L69):

```
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string accessToken = await GetAuthorizationHeader();
            ServiceClientCredentials credentials = new TokenCredentials(accessToken);
            StorageManagementClient StorageManagement = new StorageManagementClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
        }

        public static async Task<string> GetAuthorizationHeader()
        {
            ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(applicationId, password);
            var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId);
            var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", cc);

            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
            }

            string token = result.AccessToken;

            return token;
        }
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get ClientCredential to work in the AzureFunction. However, some of the documents you linked to led me to the ultimate fix.  I followed steps on this page to create a service principal with a secret key:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal 

Then I used this documentation to figure out the format of a connection string to use for the token provider:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/service-to-service-authentication#running-the-application-using-a-service-principal

Answer (score 0):

After following instructions on creating an [Application Resgistration in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal), this is the code I ended up getting to work:

```
var azureAuthConnectionString = $"RunAs=App;AppId={appId};TenantId={tenantId};AppKey={appKey}";
AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider(azureAuthConnectionString);
string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/");
ServiceClientCredentials credentials = new TokenCredentials(accessToken);
StorageManagementClient StorageManagement = new StorageManagementClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };
```